# which shell will sudo use to execute a shell script without the shebang line

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, sudo

My environment is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and the `sudo` version is 1.8.3p1.

First I login as a normal user:

```
$ whoami
fin

$ cat /etc/passwd | grep -i "root\|fin"
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
fin:x:1000:1000:This is a normal user:/home/fin:/bin/bash

$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Mar 30  2012 /bin/sh -> dash

$ ls -l /bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 920788 Apr  3  2012 /bin/bash

$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

$ ps | grep "$$" | awk '{ print $4 }'
bash

$ ls -l ./test.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 fin fin 37 Sep 27 16:46 test.sh

$ cat ./test.sh
ps | grep "$$" | awk '{ print $4 }'

$ ./test.sh
bash

$ sudo ./test.sh
sh
```

I suppose the last output should also be `bash` because `/etc/passwd` shows that root uses `bash`, am I missing any points about `sudo`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It uses `_PATH_BSHELL` like `execvp()` which on Linux is defined as `/bin/sh` in `/usr/include/paths.h`. That should be the same as when executed with `env` or `find -exec` for instance.

It should certainly not use the user's login shell. The fact that you're seeing `bash` above is because it's `bash` (the shell you enter that command line in) that tries to execute it and when it gets a `ENOEXEC` error code from `execve` it decides to interpret it with itself instead (in `sh` compatibility mode).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so it depends on sudo implementation to decide whether to use `sh` or parse `/etc/passwd` when it receieves `ENOEXEC` error?

Comment: No, `sudo` will not use the user's login shell unless you tell it to by telling it you want to pass it a command line to interpret by a shell (with -s) as opposed to a command to execute. If a command to execute, it will behave like `execvp`, that is like the system is meant to execute commands.

Comment: @Stephane Chazelas: I think it doesn't mean system to run command. `sudo` always setup its execution enviroment prior the call to `execve()`. If you don't pass `-s`, sudo will use `_PATH_BSHELL`.

Comment: @Gnouc, Yes, sudo will use _PATH_BSHELL like the system does (in execvp(), env, find, vi most shells...), it just happen to implement its own version of `execvp()`. It may also use _PATH_BSHELL with -s if executing `$SHELL` returns ENOEXEC. See my comment to your answer for more details.

Answer (score 5):

Because you don't use `-s` option, so `sudo` will use `_PATH_BSHELL` (which is define in `/usr/include/paths.h` on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) to set `$SHELL` it run. Looking in to `sudo` source code:

```
/* Stash user's shell for use with the -s flag; don't pass to plugin. */
    if ((ud->shell = getenv("SHELL")) == NULL || ud->shell[0] == '\0') {
    ud->shell = pw->pw_shell[0] ? pw->pw_shell : _PATH_BSHELL;
    }
```

If you use `-s` option, `sudo` will use your `$SHELL` instead of `_PATH_BSHELL`:

```
$ cat ./test.sh
ps | grep "$$" | awk '{ print $4 }'

$ ./test.sh
bash

$ sudo -s ./test.sh
bash
```

Comment: Note that `-s` doesn't mean the script will be interpreted by `$SHELL`, it just means that (assuming you've been authorised to use `$SHELL` as the target user), the command is started as `$SHELL -c ./test.sh`. Shells like `bash`, `yash` or `ksh93` may choose to interpret the she-bang-less scripts with a copy of themselves, others would not and would call the system's `sh` instead.

Comment: In other words, it's **not** _$SHELL instead of _PATH_BSHELL_, it's `exec($SHELL, "-c", "./test.sh")` unconditionally instead of  `if (exec("./test.sh") == ENOEXEC) exec(_PATH_BSHELL, "./test.sh")` (pseudo-code).

Answer (score 4):

The kernel can only run binary executable images.  So how do scripts get run?  After all, I can type `my_script_without_shebang` at a shell prompt and I don't get an `ENOEXEC` error. Script execution is done not by the kernel, but by the shell.  The exec code in the shell usually looks something like:

```
/* try to run the program */
execl(program, basename(program), (char *)0);

/* the exec failed -- maybe it is a shell script without shebang? */
if (errno == ENOEXEC)
    execl ("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", program, (char *)0);
```

You can verify that with tracing a dummy shell script without shebang:

```
cat > /tmp/foo.sh <<EOF
echo
EOF

chmod u+x /tmp/foo.sh

strace /tmp/foo.sh 2>&1 | grep exec
execve("/tmp/foo.sh", ["/tmp/foo.sh"], [/* 28 vars */]) = -1 ENOEXEC (Exec format error)
```

So then, the execution proceed as Stephane described - default shell is used (in the above code snippet is hard-coded). [This nice UNIX FAQ](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part3/section-16.html) can answer more.